# "File layers" for Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, photoshop-scripting, krita

Does Photoshop have ["file layers" like Krita does](https://docs.krita.org/en/reference_manual/layers_and_masks/file_layers.html), i.e. layers whose content automatically updates from a file when that file changes?

If not natively, maybe a Photoshop script can get immediately triggered upon file changes somehow?

Comment: In Photoshop they are called [Smart Objects](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/photoshop/using/create-smart-objects.html).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Yes, it's **Smart Objects** in Photoshop

Comment: This is a link only answer, you should specify whats in the link here too or you risk being modded to oblivion.